# How to simplify exponential matrix complex output in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix-exponential

I want to use MATLAB to find $e^{\mathbf{A}t}$ for
$$\mathbf{X'}=\begin{pmatrix} -3 & -1 \\ \phantom{-}2 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\mathbf{X}$$
this is what I wrote in the command window

```
A=[-3 -1 ; 2 -1]
syms t
expm(A*t)
```

And I do get an output, but I want to simplify the output because it is in complex, so I write

```
simplify(expm(A*t))
```

but I keep getting the same output. Does anyone have any idea how to simplify it? This was a question from a differential equations textbook, the question was

> In the case of complex output, utilize the software to do the simplification.

and that is what I am trying to do here, but it is not working.

Comment: I don't have MATLAB, but are you getting $$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 e^{-2 t} (\cos (t)-\sin (t)) & -e^{-2 t} \sin (t) \\
 2 e^{-2 t} \sin (t) & e^{-2 t} (\sin (t)+\cos (t)) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: What does simplify(expm(A*t),'Criterion','preferReal', 'Steps', 100) return?

Comment: @Moo This is what it returns $$\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{2}e^{-2t}\cos(t+\dfrac{\pi}{4}) & -e^{-2t}\sin t \\ 2e^{-2t}\sin t & \sqrt{2}e^{-2t}\sin(t+\dfrac{\pi}{4})\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @Moo wouldn't it be possible to get the output exactly as the one you wrote in the first comment? It is the output I am looking for.

Comment: @Moo I made a small change and wrote simplify(expm(A*t),'Criterion','preferReal', 'Steps', 50) and I got the exact answer as in your first comment. Thank you, that was very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, Matlab does not know that your $t$ is the time, i.e., that it is real. And by default it assumes that $t$ is complex. If you want to tell to Matlab that the variable is real, then define it as

```
syms t real
```

Then `pretty(simplify(expm(A*t)))` returns

```
/                      /     pi \                                  \
| sqrt(2) exp(-2 t) cos| t + -- |,        -exp(-2 t) sin(t)        |
|                      \      4 /                                  |
|                                                                  |
|                                                       /     pi \ |
|        exp(-2 t) sin(t) 2,       sqrt(2) exp(-2 t) sin| t + -- | |
\                                                       \      4 / /
```